# How to get all products from all categories

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Could anyone assist me with my code I am trying to scrape products and prices from a patisserie website however it only retrieves the products on the main page. The rest of the products which are classified in categories have the same tags and attributes however when I run my code only products on the main page only appear. Here is my code;

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

cakes = []

url = "https://mrbakeregypt.com/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
articles = soup.find_all("div", class_="grid-view-item product-card")

for item in articles:
    product = item.find("div", class_="h4 grid-view-item__title product- 
    card__title").text
    price_regular = item.find("div", class_="price__regular").text.strip().replace('\n', 
    '')

    item_cost = {"name": product,
                 "cost": price_regular

                 }
    `[![enter code here][1]][1]`cakes.append(item_cost)
```

Comment: Since you only provided the main page url the script you run will only retrieve the main page elements you specified. If you want the script to scrape the cakes category you will need to provide that url, `url_for_cake = "https://mrbakeregypt.com/collections/cakes"`

Comment: So i need to do that with all Categories !!! but I am quite confused is there is anything that can iterate through all categories or that's not possible I may ask some dump questions however I am new to python and still learning. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned you have to process all collections / categories and one approache could be to collect the links from your `baseUrl` - Note I used a `set comprehension` to get only unique urls and avoid to iterate the same categorie more than one time:

```
urlList = list(set(baseUrl+a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href*="collection"]')))
```

Now you could itarate this `urlList` to scrape your informations:

```
...
for url in urlList:
    
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
    
    articles = soup.find_all("div", class_="grid-view-item product-card")
...
```

###### Example

Take a look it also handles the type / categorie of product and both prices, so you could filter based on these in your `dataframe`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

baseUrl = "https://mrbakeregypt.com"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(baseUrl, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(baseUrl).content)

urlList = list(set(baseUrl+a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href*="collection"]')))

data = []

for url in urlList:
    
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
    
    articles = soup.find_all("div", class_="grid-view-item product-card")

    for item in articles:
        
        data.append({
            'name': item.a.text.strip(),
            'price_regular': item.find("div", class_="price__regular").dd.text.split()[-1].strip(),
            'price_sale': item.find("div", class_="price__sale").dd.text.split()[-1].strip(),
            'type': url.split('/')[-1],
            'url': baseUrl+item.a.get('href')
        })
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

###### Output

|  | name | price_regular | price_sale | type | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Mini Sandwiches Mix - 20 Pieces Bread Basket | 402 | 402 | sandwiches | https://mrbakeregypt.com/collections/sandwiches/products/mini-sandwiches-mix-bread-basket |
| 1 | Spiced Aubergine Mini Sandwiches - Box 2 Pieces | 35 | 35 | sandwiches | https://mrbakeregypt.com/collections/sandwiches/products/spiced-aubergine-mini-sandwich |
| 2 | Tuna Mini Sandwiches - Box 2 Pieces | 49 | 49 | sandwiches | https://mrbakeregypt.com/collections/sandwiches/products/tuna-mini-sandwich |
| 3 | Turkey Coleslaw Mini Sandwiches - Box 2 Pieces | 45 | 45 | sandwiches | https://mrbakeregypt.com/collections/sandwiches/products/turkey-coleslaw-mini-sandwich |
| 4 | Roast Beef Mini Sandwiches - Box 2 Pieces | 49 | 49 | sandwiches | https://mrbakeregypt.com/collections/sandwiches/products/roast-beef-mini-sandwich |

...

Comment: i tried it however i am getting error at line 9 soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)  should it be requests.get(Baseurl) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot mate it works properly it was my mistake cheeeeeeers.

Comment: You are right, fixed that in the example to 'baseUrl'